# Android NDK Cross Compile sys/signal.h: No such file or directory

Tags: android, android-ndk, cmake, cross-compiling

I am compiling gdcm with cross compile but it gives following error for

sys/signal.h: No such file or directory ( NDK does not have that I know it)

but is there any alternative I can resolve that error for Cross compilation of library.

```
In file included from /home/kirtan.patel/Desktop/GDCMMob/Build/Utilities/socketxx/socket++/config.h:135:0,
                 from /home/kirtan.patel/Desktop/GDCMMob/GDCMSource/Utilities/socketxx/socket++/sockstream.h:22,
                 from /home/kirtan.patel/Desktop/GDCMMob/GDCMSource/Utilities/socketxx/socket++/sockstream.cpp:49:
/home/kirtan.patel/Desktop/GDCMMob/GDCMSource/Utilities/socketxx/socket++/local.h:40:24: fatal error: sys/signal.h: No such file or directory
 #include <sys/signal.h>
                        ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [Utilities/socketxx/socket++/CMakeFiles/socketxx.dir/sockstream.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Utilities/socketxx/socket++/CMakeFiles/socketxx.dir/all] Error 2
```

Comment: You could to put your Android.mk or CmakeLists.

Comment: Hi Alex CMakeList is correct one but #include <sys/signal.h> is not there in Android NDK as I came to know this as I can compile same library for Linux and this error comes only while using cross compiler for android.

Answer (score 1):

sys/signal.h is only available in latest Android NDK and under platforms above and equal to 21 (/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/include/sys/signal.h).

I had this issue while building RTKLib and fixed this using latest Toolchain.

Thanks,
Himanshu

Comment: android-ndk-r16b doesn't contain include folder, but then android-ndk-14 has this folder.